# SQL multi if statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, Data and Rate. In the Data table, I have the following info:-

[image]

As for Rate table, I hv the following info:-

[image]

The final output should be in this format:-

[image]

The conditions:-

a.  If both Local Currency and Document Current are the same, the ExRate must be equal to 1;

b.  If they are not the same, then the ExRate will be based on the Local Currency in the Rate table.

How can I generate the above output?

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images. (And some aren't even allowed to see images...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `LEFT JOIN` and `CASE`

```
SELECT d.*, 
        CASE
            WHEN d.DocumentCurrency = r.LocalCurrency then 1
            ELSE r.ExRate
        END AS ExRate
FROM Data d
LEFT JOIN Rate r on d.DocumentCurrency = r.DocumentCurrency
                    AND d.LocalCurrency = r.LocalCurrency
```